# Compiling/importing files from the assets folder

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently working in a project with `vue.js` v2, I've been for 2 hours trying to include/compile some files in the assets folder, when I `npm run dev` or `npm run build` it doesn't include the files I want, in fact it doesn't include any css/js files on assets folder.

How and where I specify (in the right order) the files I want to import?

I followed the [documentation install](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#NPM), and everything are as default.

```
- my-project
    - build
    - config
    - dist
    - node_modules
    - src
        - assets
            - css
            - js
            - plugins
        - components
        - router
        - App.vue
        - main.js
    - static
```

Comment: Are these js and css files you are trying to load with `<script src="foo">` tag in the index.html or are the files you are referencing from within you *vue templates?

Comment: @MarkM, the thing is, if I import like `<script src="local_file/foo">` then when run build the path will be wrong. Where can I specify the files to be "compiled", I worked with gulp and it was strait forward, I guess with webpack it is too, but I didn't find anything that helped me on this. Thanks

Comment: If your JavaScript files are not referenced within your application then when you `npm run build` they shall not be included. Most things you are going to want to include via your `main.js` so there useable, other things you can put into your `index.html` but must be present inside the static folder.

Comment: You can also include things in your components locally using an `import` statement.

Comment: Hello @lix, I tried via main.js (https://pastebin.com/GsNUasiS), indeed but the error that gives me it is: `This dependency was not found:

* jquery in ./src/assets/plugins/jquery-countto/jquery.countTo.js, ./src/assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js`. So I guess it is compiling in the wrong order. Regarding to " include things in your components " that would be dificult because many things are comumn

Comment: You should be using import rather than require

Comment: It's also more efficient to include what your after using npm and then importing from `node_modules`

Comment: @lix, the error telling me jquery isn't found remains. I can't import via nodule modules because it's a template that I'm refactoring to vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147659/discussion-between-li-x-and-hula-hula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was resolved by including `jQuery` via webpack module inside the webpack config so that his JavaScript files which use jQuery can be loaded globally into his config.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html

```
 alias: {
    'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
    'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
    'jquery': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/jquery/src/jquery'),
    'directives': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/directives')
  }
```